# XNA Transparent Window Form

Tags: winforms, xna, transparency

trying to implement an xna game with a transparent window (showing the desktop or whatever behind it). Found a few people asking but no relevant answers.

I can get the form and set TransparencyKey

```
Form gameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
gameForm.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
```

then in the draw method i clear it to Red, and from my understanding Transparency key should remove anything red from being drawn, so the red background should go poof!

Does anyone know if I'm missing something or has more insight?

Comment: When you correctly make the game window transparent, you will see black screen. I'm not sure you can make *the transparent game window*, but you can simulate it by grabbing screenshots of the area behind the client area of the game window, though it is usually very slow.

Comment: Yeah, I've done alot of research on it, and I *think* it is impossible due to Forms using GDI+ and xna using D3D. I am currently using a screenshot to mimic the look and feel of it, thought not happy with it. Luckily the game is very simple, so I'm not seeing any performance issues. 

If anyone ever discovers a workaround to implement this, you will have my praise!